# Prevent VirtualBox bridge network disconnection overnight

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, bridge

I'm running VirtualBox on Windows 10. When I leave it overnight, I can no longer reach it via the network in the morning, but the VM is still running and responsive within its own window. It's using a bridge mode adaptor.

How can I keep the network going all the time? At the moment I have to completely shut down the VM (rebooting it within the instance doesn't work) and restart it from the VirtualBox VM list.

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: @miravalls Nope. Not at all. When Windows goes to sleep, the VM can't receive pings due to having no power. I can't force Windows not to sleep just for the sake of convenience. Something about the virtual adapter isn't in the same state when it wakes up.

Comment: The script was meant to be executed *from* the VM, pinging the router or some other host, so that the virtual adapter does not get into the weird state. In my experience, it is common that the virtual adapters get in this state after the Windows host goes to sleep.

Comment: @miravalls How can the VM keep pinging when its host machine is asleep?

Comment: I though the virtual bridge was crashing due to inactivity, not because the host was going to sleep. That information is missing in you post. If the host is sleeping, it can't receive or send any traffic. AFAIK, a host sleeping is effectively off. You may need to check if you can send Wake-On-LAN packets to power it back on. You may need to activate it in the BIOS. Otherwise, I don't know any automatic way to recover from sleep mode. If you power back on the PC, does the network work? Did you try restarting the VirtualBox service in windows task manager after powering back on?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the ip and dns information on your vm, in the morning?

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to reach the PC in the morning after it falls in sleep mode during the night, did you try to set a timer to power it back on?

Maybe this [tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/119028/how-to-make-your-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/) helps.